# Error regarding running projects on WAMP which contain Zend_Session classes

Tags: zend-framework, session, ssl, wamp

I cannot run on WAMP Zend Projects containing `Zend_Session` classes.

After checking httpd's error log, I found this entry and other errors all connected with load of `Zend_Session`.

> [ssl:warn] [pid 5340:tid 216] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]

I've tried to open another project which doesn't contain any `Zend_Session` and it works. How could I solve this, in order to be able to include `Zend_Session` classes within my projects and successfully run it with WAMP?

Comment: did you already read this? http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/SSLSessionCache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with your Apache SSL configuration.
Configure your SSL module as below:

```xml
<IfModule ssl_module>
    SSLSessionCache "shmcb:C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.17/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
    SSLSessionCacheTimeout 300
    SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
    SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
```

Maybe you should also read the [`SSLSessionCache`](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/SSLSessionCache) documentation.

Comment: What do you mean read the documentation, if everyone did that SO would be a ghost town. (He says with loads of sarcasm) :)